# Double queries in rails console when using Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I noticed that I have double queries when using rails console with Heroku. I didn't get this issue earlier. Any ideas what can cause it?

I have already read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23503238/active-record-running-all-queries-twice/30175074), but it didn't solve my problem.

```
hubert@hubert-K54LY:~/ror/angipl$ heroku run rails c
Running rails c on ⬢ angipl... up, run.3439
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.6)
irb(main):001:0> Word.find(1)
  Word Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Word Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Word id: 1, en: "academic", pl: "pracownik naukowy", user_id: 1, created_at: "2016-09-18 07:17:02", updated_at: "2016-09-18 12:05:51", good_count: 4, bad_count: 1, verified: true>
irb(main):002:0>
```

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4'
end
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development


gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.5'
gem "haml-rails", "~> 0.9"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'active_link_to'
# gem 'commontator', '~> 4.11.1'
gem 'devise-i18n'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"
gem 'draper', '~> 2.1'
gem 'decent_exposure', '~> 2.3', '>= 2.3.3'
gem 'decent_decoration', '~> 0.0.6'
gem 'faker', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.3'
gem 'react-rails'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.4'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem "better_errors"
  gem 'capybara'
end

group :production do
  gem 'puma'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.1'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'simplecov', :require => false
end
```

Comment: Have you seen [this issue](https://github.com/heroku/rails_stdout_logging/issues/1) on the rails_stdout_logging GitHub repo?

Comment: Yes. I did, but I didn't found there solution for my rails console issue.

Answer (score 1):

as referenced in a comment this basically has an answer already on the heroku issues page [here](https://github.com/heroku/rails_stdout_logging/issues/1).

But just to sum it up:

Two SQL queries are not actually occurring. It's just an issue with the logger printing the line twice.

The way to remove the duplicate message is to add this line to the `Procfile` (the file which tells Heroku how to run the app):

```
web: rackup -p $PORT
```

This makes the app start with `rackup` instead of `rails server`.

If that doesn't work see the issues thread for more advice.

Comment: I created file named `Procfile` in the root of application. It didn't help.